# My hard drive shows up in gparted but not in the bios

Tags: arch-linux, boot, partition

I figured a good way to learn some stuff would be to install arch a couple different ways, so here's what I did.

I'm using https://sourceforge.net/projects/revenge-installer/, which I put on a USB. After disconnecting my other drives, I booted from the USB, and everything seems fine. I set up my partitions: first is a 64gb swap partition (I had heard the rule of thumb for swap was 2x ram), then a 16gb root partition (I'm not using a separate boot partition, so this one also has the boot and esp flags), then I put 3 more 16gb ext4 partitions (for future installs I want to try out), then the rest is for /home. I go through the rest of the installer without any trouble, and reboot.

However the hard drive I installed to doesn't show up at all in the bios. So I put in the live usb and return to the installation environment. While I'm there, I mount /dev/sdb2 (the root partition I installed) and verify that /boot contains its files. As far as I can tell, nothing's wrong there, but I'm far from an expert. I also checked the drive in gparted to make sure the partitions are there as expected, and they are. What might explain this, and what should I check?

Comment: Your ESP should be a separate (small) FAT partition, usually it's the first partition on the drive. See [EFI system partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_system_partition). Your 64GB swap partition is probably overkill, but it won't hurt. I'd select a smaller swap (or no swap at all), but larger root partitions.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. So it'll look like: [300mb "/boot" fat32 +boot +esp] [48gb swap] [64gb archroot ext4] [64gb ext4]*3 [<rest> "/home" ext4]?

Comment: The mount point for the ESP should be `/boot/efi` or `/efi` (the `/boot` directory is then inside the root partition `/` and not separate), the rest looks good.